# BackgroundWorker+ProgressBar, with BackgroundWorker being in different class

Tags: c#, wpf, class, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I want to keep my main code body clean. I have a button, upon pressing this button i want my progress to fill, but i want the code of filling up the progress bar to be in the different class, where i will handle background worker as well.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    internal class WorkerClass
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, i can't change Value of progressbar (pbStatus) inside the new class. What do?

Comment: Could you include an example of how you intend to use the `WorkerClass` class?

Comment: You'd have an event in `WorkerClass` that you invoke inside `worker_ProgressChanged`, but you'd be reinventing the wheel. Consider using a `Progress<T>` object instead. You might find this article useful: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html